# Styling in php file directory

Tags: php, css

i am really feel strange that i am unable to do that simple thing now. because i do it easily early,but i dont have that codes. i am trying to create a file directory listing script. while i try to read files, i want to style it with `<td>` but as i am using one single code for file printing, i also got trouble that table is open and closing in one line every time.
here is my code

```
if($er == '.mp3' or $er == '.wav' or $er == '.amr' or $er == '.MP3' or $er == '.WAV' or $er == '.AMR' )
    {  $fname = strtok($name,'.');
        $name = str_replace(' ','_',$name);
        if ( strlen($name) <19) {
            $fnam = "$name";
        } else {
            $fnam = substr ($name, 0, 18);
        }                          
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="mp3.php?mp3='.$file.'&nm='.$name.'&br='.$folder.'"><h2>'.$fnam.'</h2></a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    }
```

the output showing only one style because for every file, its opening table and closing table. but i want table should be open only once but table-data should be open and close every time. 
any one can help?

Comment: This can't be your complete code otherwise there would be only one line. I think there is a for or while-loop around it? Then you need to move the `<table>` tags outside this function

Comment: first line: `if (in_array(strtolower($er), ['.mp3', '.wav', '.amr'])) {`

Comment: `<table>` should be before the loop, and `</table>` should be after the loop. Each file should just echo `<tr>` and `<td>`

Comment: here is full code link http://pastebin.com/L8E8wMwb

Comment: anyways thanks @Barmar